# IE 11 emulating IE5 disable <select multiple> hover event

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, html-select, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a legacy application (20+ years old) and our users have been forced to use IE11. We have some

```
<select multiple>
```

elements that have 30,000+ options in them.

We have noticed that the hover event (which colors the background grey as you hover over the options) causes all of the 30k options to be re-rendered, causing the page to drop to 1 FPS. Is there any way of disabling this kind of native highlighting?

I've tried modifying the below css properties to no avail:

```
select::-ms-value
select:hover
```

I suspect it's not possible but if anyone would know it would be here. Obviously, 30k options in a select box isn't ideal and neither is IE5 documents mode in IE11 but we don't have much choice at the moment.

Comment: supporting IE5? Wouldn't you be better off gagging yourself with a red-hot pitchfork? IE6 was bad enough... IE<6 is insta-suicide territory...

Comment: Of course, but we don't have the time or luxury of re-implementing the site to be standards based. If we did that, we'd probably just re-write the entire thing which we don't have resources for at the moment